# right alt + F4 doesn't work when using CLion in Fedora 39

Tags: fedora, gnome, keyboard-shortcuts

I recently installed Fedora 39, using Gnome on Xorg, and noticed that right Alt + F4 doesn't close the IDE the way I'm used to. left alt + F4 works fine. I was previously using Debian 12, and for CLion both Alts work fine with F4.

For some reason this is only happening on CLion. For other apps like terminal, file browser, firefox, etc., even right alt + F4 works fine on Fedora 39.

What's causing right alt+F4 to not work here?

Answer (score 0):

It was "Alternate characters key" that was causing it. For some reason, this wasn't a thing in Debian 12's older Gnome, but in Fedora 39's newer Gnome it's now a thing.

That setting is under Settings -> Keyboard. By default, it is set to "Right alt". There's no way to disable it, but I set it to "menu key" because my keyboard doesn't even have that button. After that change, right alt + F4 worked fine on CLion.